# Paypal: how to setup and process pre-approved payments?

Tags: android, paypal

Thank you for your attention and your help.

In my Android App I need:

- the user to create a pre-approved payment channel via PayPal to pay to a selected PayPal account
- after that, the app should, programmatically, if triggered, process the payment via PayPal, i.e: send the money to the selected Paypal account.

Please could somebody give me some guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To setup the preapproval profile you'll use the [Preapproval API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/).  The original call will return a preapproval key, and then you'll redirect the user over to PayPal with this key appended to the URL.  This [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) has lots of info on that.  Do a find on that page for "Preapproved Payments Flow".

The user will sign in and approve the deal and the preapproval key is valid at that point.

Then, when you trigger a payment, you'll call the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).  You can include the preapproval key in the Pay request, and this will process the payment immediately without any further authentication required.

Some people get confused here because the request still requires a return URL and a cancel URL in order to work, but those are really obsolete in this case.  When you call Pay with a preapproval key and get a successful response the transaction is done.  This can be triggered however you want and can be completely automated without any interruption.

Comment: thank you Andrew for pointing me in the right direction. I am trying to use the Preapproval API based on the samples available on PyaPal Githb, but I get the error: `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyManagerFactory SunX509 implementation not found`

Comment: @hAndrew Angell please se the question I have posted here, THANK LISA ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578289/android-java-security-nosuchalgorithmexception-keymanagerfactory-sunx509-implem